# What is the ring $\{a+b\omega|a, b\in\Bbb{Z}\}$ called, where $\omega$ is an idempotent? (subring of split-complex numbers)

Tags: ring-theory

Given the imaginary unit $j$ in the ring of [split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) ($j^2=1$), the set $\{a+b\omega|a, b\in\Bbb{Z}\}$, $\omega={1+j\over 2}$, for "imaginary unit" $j$ forms a commutative ring.  It does not appear to match the definition of an [integer ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_integers). Is there a name for this ring, or for a class of rings containing it (by analogy with [quadratic integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer))?

Comment: Would it be a lattice?

Comment: Calling $j$ "imaginary unit" feels wrong to me...

Comment: @Will - it is an example of a lattice, but that is a rather large class.  I'm looking for something analogous to [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer) or [Gaussian integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer).

Comment: @Arthur, yes, I'd be happy to use a more comfortable term if you have one...

Comment: Hmm.  I think this would normally simply be referred to as $\Bbb{Z}\oplus\Bbb{Z}$, a direct sum of rings.